# Removing "Dirty URLs"

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have a site that apparently has "dirty URLs". For example a URL that I have goes something like this:

`www.website.com/article?articleID=2` or something along the lines of that. This, to me, seems to be the only valid way of using these URL's for a dynamic site. Is there a way to change them to say, `www.website.com/article`?

Answer (score 1):

You should not just remove the ID because it's important to know which article we are opening, you should rewrite it using .htaccess's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

What will you rewrite it to depends on the nature of your website and your strategic choices, it can be just:

`www.website.com/title-goes-here`

Or if the title of the article can be found elsewhere, you can make it:

`www.website.com/title-goes-here-id`

Or even:

`www.website.com/category-name/title-goes-here-id`

Comment: Is there another way of perhaps sending the ID to the page?

Comment: the way of sending the ID through URL won't change, the rewrite engine will receive `www.website.com/title-goes-here-id` for example and calls `www.website.com/article?articleID=id`. All you have to do is find some tutorials of .htaccess URL rewriting.